# Sharing an instance of ehcache with multiple jboss web applications using different classloaders

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ehcache

I've got several web applications running inside JBoss, each of which has it's own class loader. I'm using ehcache as my second level hibernate cache. Is it possible to share a single cache between all of the applications on the server?